# Left/right swiping in my app triggers an action that saves data to my DB. However fast swiping causes many saves to fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asynchronous, parse-platform

I've finished implementing a swipe feature similar to tinder but running into problems when saving objects.

I have 2 columns in the currentUser's row in my DB. One column hold an array of acceptedUsers (users have been liked) and the other is a rejectedUsers column that holds an array of rejected users (users that have been left swiped).

**This is how my DB is updated upon swipe:**

```
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
{
    NSString *swipedUserId = [[[userBeingSwipedArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    [currentUserImagesRow addUniqueObject:swipedUserId forKey:@"rejectedUsers"];
    [currentUserImagesRow saveInBackground];
```

This works fine when I left about 2+ seconds between swipes. However fast swiping causes some saves to fail.

Is there a better way to do this without spoiling the users experience of the app?

I've saved multiple rows to my database before using for loops and this has always worked for me. I thought parse.com would be able to handle the speed of the saving.

I'm using both swift and objective-c for this project.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Check if object that you add exists in rejectedUsers. Add and save only if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a fun problem.  I think the way to go is to decouple the swiping and the saving a little bit more.  Start with a collection of what needs saving...

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *toSave;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL busySaving;

    // on swipe
    [self.toSave addObject: currentUserImagesRow];
    [self doSaves];

- (void)doSaves {
    // we get called because of user interaction, and we call ourselves
    // recursively when finished.  keep state so these requests don't pile up
    if (self.busySaving) return;

    if (self.toSave.count) {
        self.busySaving = YES;
        [PFObject saveAllInBackground:self.toSave block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            self.busySaving = NO;
            // remove just the elements that were saved, remaining aware that
            // new ones might have arrived while the last save was happening
            NSMutableArray *removes = [@[] mutableCopy];
            for (PFObject *object in self.toSave) {
                if (!object.isDirty) [removes addObject:object];
            }
            [self.toSave removeObjectsInArray:removes];
            [self doSaves];
        }];
    }
}
```

Now, instead of processing single saves, we can handle small batches.  A user swipe causes a single save, and we block additional requests until the current one is complete.  During the current request, we let more saves queue up as the user continues to interact.  We call ourselves recursively after a save in case one or more records were queued.  If none were, the recursive call ends immediately.

**EDIT** - Saving just one object is easier, just do the same blocking trick and recursive call at the end, but no need to track or save batches...

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL busySaving;

    // on swipe
    [self doSaves];

- (void)doSaves {
    if (self.busySaving) return;
    if (currentUserImagesRow.isDirty) {
        self.busySaving = YES;
        [currentUserImagesRow saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            self.busySaving = NO;
            [self doSaves];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution. (Voted)

Comment: This makes sense. I've tried to implement it but it doesn't seem to be working. I've declared the properties in my .h file and synthesized them in in .m. I've cleared the doSaves method and added the //on swipe calls to the swipe methods. It makes one save and that's it. Just to be clear currentUserImagesRow is the row for the current user where I'm saving the    objectId of the user that is being swiped.

Comment: I should have looked more closely at your code to begin with.  You're saving just that one object, changing one of its columns as the user takes action.  One idea is why not just do no saving until the user is done swiping, then save the one object in its current state at the end.  Anyway, I think my approach still applies -- and more simply -- see edit.  Hope that's useful.

Comment: It doesn't look like any edits have been made to your code. I did mess around with my code for a while but can't seem to get this to work. I really like the way of having objects queue up waiting to be saved.

Comment: Came up with a solution with the help yours but ultimately it's your answer so marking yours as correct

Comment: Hmm.  Sorry about the edit.  I made a complete edit and thought I saved it.  Just did a quick redo of the edit.  Glad to hear its working for you now, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Danh led me to my answer. There was an issue on my side which was causing the problem mentioned in the comments above. The same ID was being used after each swipe because I didn't remove it from the array that held my user objects. Below is how I solved the issue and used the Danh's answer to find my solution.

```
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card
{
    NSString *swipedUserId = [[[userBeingSwipedArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    // I save the swiped users id and the key for the column it will 
    // be saved in e.g. if liked then "acceptedUsers" if notLiked then
    // "rejectedUsers" so that the doSave method saves to correct column
    NSArray *array = @[swipedUserId, @"acceptedUsers"];

    [self.toSave addObject: array];

    //remove user from array since he/she is now saved
    [userBeingSwipedArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[userBeingSwipedArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    [self doSaves];
```

**and then:**

```
- (void)doSaves {

    if (self.busySaving) return;

    if (self.toSave.count) {
        self.busySaving = YES;

        NSArray *arrayWithSwipedUsersIdAndKeyForColumn = [self.toSave objectAtIndex:0];

        [currentUserImagesRow addUniqueObject:[arrayWithSwipedUsersIdAndKeyForColumn objectAtIndex:0] forKey:[arrayWithSwipedUsersIdAndKeyForColumn objectAtIndex:1]];
        [currentUserImagesRow saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            self.busySaving = NO;

            //remove object that was just saved seeing as it is no longer needed
            [self.toSave removeObjectIdenticalTo:arrayWithSwipedUsersIdAndKeyForColumn];
            [self doSaves];
        }];
    }
}
```

Saving now works 100% of the time providing there is an internet connection. I can swipe as fast as I wish and objects always get saved.